# Can you pass different env variable to each pod with helm in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm using helm to deploy My code to kubernetes, is it possible to pass different env variable
To each pod(replicate) ?

Comment: As with all good things, the answer is both "it depends" and "the devil's in the details"; please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section in order to provide an example of what you're trying to do, the reasons it's not currently working, and to show us whether you have read [the fine manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20220322025053/https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/)

Comment: This question already seems to have been asked several times; see for example [How to make an environment variable different across two pods of the same deployment in kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628474/how-to-make-an-environment-variable-different-across-two-pods-of-the-same-deploy) (short answer: every Deployment creates identical Pods, so if you need different environment variables, for the most part you need multiple Deployments).