# Is it possible to apply different label to different replicas in the same kubernetes deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

We want to apply different label and scheduling strategy to different labels in a kubernetes deployment. Is it possible?

Comment: To apply different label and scheduling strategies to different labels, you can use [label selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors) in your deployment objects. This will allow you to define criteria for selecting objects based on their labels. By specifying different label selectors in your deployment objects, you can control which Pods are scheduled on which nodes based on their labels. For example, you can use a label selector to specify the pods that a deployment should manage or the pods to which a service should route traffic.

Comment: Refer to this [blog](https://www.split.io/blog/kubernetes-labels-best-practices/#managing-labels-with-label-selectors)  by CHRISTOPHER JOHNSON.

Comment: Every Pod in a Deployment is identical, so this doesn't seem possible. [How to make an environment variable different across two pods of the same deployment in kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628474/how-to-make-an-environment-variable-different-across-two-pods-of-the-same-deploy) has a similar answer: to have different environment variables per Pod, you usually need different Deployments.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible* to have different labels per replica. Your question does not explain *why* you want to do this unfortunately.

What you might be looking for is advanced scheduling techniques to make sure that pods spread across nodes. Take a look at [Affinity and Anti-Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity). What you can do is:

- Set node affinity, making sure that replicas go to nodes with specific labels.
- Set inter-pod affinity or anti-affinity. This can e.g. be used to make sure that pods of the same Deployment never end up on the same node together.

If this doesn't cut it, it's likely you should reconsider if those pods should really be in the same `Deployment`. Maybe you want one `Deployment` per "strategy".

* strictly speaking, you *could* maybe manually label them, but you really really don't want to do that. It's not a solution, especially since it will be after scheduling.